# Visual Studio create release file with all files embeded

Tags: visual-studio

I would lik to make 1 exe-file (win32) with all obj, idp, pdb... files embeded to make it easier to copy the program and use it on other computers, can anyone help me?

Comment: pdb contains debug information, there is no point embedding this in the exe as there is no point copying debug builds on other computers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need obj, idp, pdb... files to run on another computer.

Start by selecting the Release configuration and see what ends up in the output folder. Most likely it's just 1 file.

You can embed Text, Xml and in principal even DLL files but it is not always worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I see it is working properly at this moment, but I did have some errors before and I see my question is quiet stupid :)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply run the generated program on another computer, just copy the .exe and any associated dll files.  The pdb file is a debug information database that is not actually needed to run the program - only to load it in the debugger with specific information.  The other files are intermediate files created during the build process.

If you don't want to have to install the Visual C++ Runtime on the target machine, or rely on it being there, you will want to go into the Project Settings -> C/C++ Settings -> Code Generation and select that you want the "Multithreaded" library instead of the "Multithreaded DLL" library (or equivalent).  This will embed the C++ runtime into your program.

Of course if you're trying to copy the project over to perhaps do more debugging or development on another computer, just pack it all into a zip file.